optimization of STRCMP
I have set myself the task of optimizing the strcmp function in C. I have approached this task in two ways:

Creating a new string comparison function in assembly language.
Implementing the strcmp functionality using "intrinsics", where strings are represented by 256-bit integer registers.
After compiling the code, I observed that the execution time was not as expected.

strcmp     works 0.000002 seconds
my_strcmp  works 0.000851 seconds
my_strcmp2 works 0.017444 seconds
I would appreciate your advice on how the strcmp function can be optimized to achieve faster execution times. The string length is limited to 32 characters in this context.
Compilation: nasm -g -f elf64 my_strcmp2.asm -o my_strcmp2.o
g++ my_strcmp2.o main.cpp -march=znver3 -O3 -o app
main.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int my_strcmp(const char* word1, const char* word2);
extern "C" int my_strcmp2(const char* word1, const char* word2);
double timer(int (*func)(const char*, const char*));

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    const char* word1 = "my name is";
    const char* word2 = "my name are";

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        j = strcmp(word1, word2);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "strcmp     : %lf seconds\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        j = my_strcmp(word1, word2);
    }
    end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "my_strcmp  : %lf seconds\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        j = my_strcmp2(word1, word2);
    }
    end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "my_strcmp2 : %lf seconds\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}

int my_strcmp(const char* word1, const char* word2)
{

    __m256i str_reg_1 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i*)word1);
    __m256i str_reg_2 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i*)word2);
    __m256i res_cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(str_reg_1, str_reg_2);
    int mask = ~_mm256_movemask_epi8(res_cmp);

    return mask;
}

my_strcmp2.asm:
global my_strcmp2
section .text

my_strcmp2:
    cycle:
        cmp byte [rel rdi], 0x00
        je check_equal
        mov dl, byte [rel rsi]
        cmp byte [rel rdi], dl
        jne not_equal
        add rdi, 1
        add rsi, 1
    jmp cycle

    not_equal:
        mov rax, 0x01
        ret

    check_equal:
        cmp byte [rel rsi], 0x00
        jne not_equal
        xor rax, rax
        ret


It is a fairly certain bet that the authors of the standard library will have worked quite a long time on making strcmp very optimized. Few programmers will be able to beat most  standard-library implementations.

On a different note, why did you tag your question with C++ code with the C language tag? And why do you write what is really C code in a C++ source file, and build with a C++ compiler?

Knowing that your strings are never longer than 32 bytes helps.  Do you also know if access to the first 32 bytes of the strings is always possible, even if they are shorter than 32 bytes?  I spent a few weeks writing a fast strcmp for the FreeBSD project and most of the difficulty lies in dealing with the possibility of page faults.  If you know there won't be faults, it's a lot easier.

Your implementation is quite naive, it's a simple loop using standard X86 instructions. Actual strcmp implementations use special SIMD instructions, vectored instructions and/or assembly tricks depending on the platform and the available instruction  set. Your code is probably even slower than the code produced by a modern compiler.

If you can guarantee these two things, it's quite easy: load both strings into ymm registers, then compare them for equality and compare one of them for equality with a vector of all zeroes.  The strings are equal if there is no mismatch on or before the first NUL byte.  Otherwise load the location of the first mismatch and compare the two characters to get the lexicographical ordering of the strings.

Also, compilers may not be able to optimize a function containing inline assembly/intrinsics, in case the optimizer is not "assembler aware". It might then regard such as "unknown side effects". Whereas a strcmp library function call may be replaced with whatever suits the context - for example with small input < 64 bits it might just do some manner of 64 bit comparison in a single instruction and be done with it. it's a different thing to optimize C code with assembler and optimizing C code into assembler.

You are not benchmarking properly. The compiler can optimize the loops (since the result is unused) and the input is known, so constant propagation will work. This includes calls to strcmp since the compiler knows that functions results. See Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? Also, lddqu is obsolete. See what's the difference between _mm256_lddqu_si256 and _mm256_loadu_si256

Your code is C++, as evidenced by extern "C" and the use of g++. Tag C++ for C++ code, not C.

Have you actually profiled your solution (using a good profiling tool)? If not your timings are meaningless. Also ou're much more likely to run out of memory bandwidth here than you are of running out of CPU power. Branching could also be a bottlenck here so try to minimize that too (failed branches are very expensive) .. so all in all consider this a learning effort without any real practical benefits

@Someprogrammerdude and, even better, some compilers don't even call any libraries and outright treat strcmp as a builtin function...

GCC knows what strcmp does and can see that this code:
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        j = strcmp(word1, word2);
    }

is equivalent to:
j = strcmp(word1, word2);

Therefore, it optimizes the loop away and evaluates strcmp during compilation, replacing it with a constant, and the time per iteration is effectively zero. It is impossible for you to beat this with your own implementation of strcmp.
You might measure the time of the library strcmp by adding -fnobuiltin-strcmp to the compilation switches and declaring j volatile. You should examine the assembly generated by the compiler to see whether it is actually calling strcmp and is doing so in a loop.
